# Can't limit my script to parse a specific section from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script in `python` to scrape the description within `Plot` from a webpage. The thing is the description are within several `p` tags. There are other `p` tags as well which I do not wish to scrape. As soon as my script is done parsing the description of `Plot`, It should stop. However, my below script parses all the `p` tags through the end starting from `Plot` section.

***How can I limit my script to parse the description of the `Plot` only?***

This what I've written:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_(film)"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    res = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    plot = [item.text for item in soup.select_one("#Plot").find_parent().find_next_siblings("p")]
    print(plot)
```

Comment: How does your HTML document look like ?

Comment: Do you want to get all text content between headers `"Plot[edit]"` and `"Cast[edit]"`? Do you want bs4 solution only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not mandatory for you to use beautifulSoup, you can try below to get required piece of text content

```
from lxml import html

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    res = s.get(url)
    source = html.fromstring(res.content)
    plot = [item.text_content() for item in source.xpath('//p[preceding::h2[1][span="Plot"]]')]
    print(plot)
```

Comment: As long as you are online, there is always hope @sir Andersson. One thing I could not understand: why you used `.text_content()` instead of `.text`? Thanks for your perfect answer.

Comment: `text` will return only child text nodes of `p` (ignoring descendant text nodes) while `text_content()` returns all the text content between opening `<p>` and closing  `</p>` tag

Answer (score 1):

You can pick paragraphs before next header, like

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    res = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

    plot_start = [item for item in soup.select_one("#Plot").find_parent().find_next_siblings()]
    plot = []
    for item in plot_start:
        if item.name != 'h2':
            plot.append(item.text)
        else:
            break
    print(plot)
```

Comment: Another awesome answer!! + one for this. I wish I could select both of them. Thanks.